# Tag synonym request: [mac-os] to [os-x] (or vice versa)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

The upcoming version of "OS X", which is macOS 10.12 Sierra, changes the canonical name of the operating system series from "OS X" to "macOS".

Therefore, I suggest that either to move the tag [os-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/os-x) to [mac-os](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-os) and leave a synonym for [os-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/os-x), or make [mac-os](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-os) be the synonym of [os-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/os-x).

Here's a [related discussion](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2812/should-the-osx-tag-be-renamed-to-macos) on *Ask Different Meta*:

Comment: Given all tag names are lower-cased, if we go ahead with this I would recommend [mac-os] over [macos] for readability.

Comment: @fredley Uhh, never mind the deleted comment if you got a notification, but a quick look on *Ask Different* (apple.stackexchange.com) revealed that they have different tag conventions, (e. g. [osx] while ours is [os-x]), so we could go ahead with [mac-os] even if other sites use [macos].

Comment: Can't this wait for Sierra to go golden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done. I've mapped  [macos](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos) and [mac-os](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-os) to [os-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/os-x). Since  Sierra isn't even out yet it doesn't make much sense   to switch away from [os-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/os-x) until then, provided we do that at all. Despite the name change I suspect most folks are going to call it OS X anyways, so we'll probably just want to stick with that even after fall rolls around.