# Rename [os-x] → [macos], like how Ask Different tags the operating system

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

As of September 2016, OS X has been renamed to [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) (presumably to align with Apple's other operating systems iOS and watchOS). There have now been two operating systems released under this moniker (macOS 10.11 "Sierra" and macOS 10.12 "High Sierra").

Given that it's been over a year since then, would it be possible to rename [os-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/os-x) to [macos](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos), keeping the old tag as a synonym? This would be consistent with [how Ask Different (a.k.a. Apple.SE) does it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos).

<sub>There was a previous meta topic called  [Tag synonym request: [mac-os] to [os-x] (or vice versa)](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11760/47878), and the consensus was to make [os-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/os-x) the parent tag because macOS 10.11 "Sierra" was not released yet. Now that two versions have been released with the name, I think that the reason for that is no longer valid.</sub>

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Apple's update/versioning system, so forgive me if this is a dumb question. Wouldn't [macOS] be better as a brand new tag? Or is this the equivalent of Microsoft saying "all Windows operating systems will now be called Doors, so we've got Doors XP, Doors 7, Doors 8.1, and Doors 10, etc."?

Comment: @MageXy Tags on Stack Exchange don’t distinguish between lower case and capital letters. If they did, then yes, I would say [macOS] would be better.

Comment: Sorry, I meant: is the new "macOS" a new operating system version, or is Apple just retroactively renaming all of their old Mac operating systems with a new name?

Comment: @MageXy The name change isn't retroactive. If you look at [Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS#Release_history), we have Mac OS X 10.0-10.7, OS X 10.8-10.11, and macOS 10.12 onwards. Also, the "classic" operating system is "Mac OS 8", etc. For our purposes, there isn't really a strong reason to have separate tags for Mac OS X, OS X, and macOS, so having one tag for the whole line makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The synonym has been flipped:

- [os-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/os-x) → [macos](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macos)

Comment: Thanks! Technically, there is ["Classic" Mac OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_Mac_OS) (version 9 and less) and the now they're calling it [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS). What's old is new. Except spaces. Those are still old apparently.

Comment: @Thunderforge Apple removed the space because they're courageous